# Are conflicting constraints necessarily a bad thing?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

Hey guys I'm working on an iOS app and using autolayout and interface builder to create views for my app. I got into a debate with one of my coworkers regarding those Xcode warnings

> "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints..."

- In my opinion I feel like you should set constraints in such a way so that these warnings never appear.
- He was arguing that as long as your views are laying out the way you want then it doesn't really matter if you get these warnings or not, its all about what then end user sees.

I've only been doing this for about 2 years so just wanted to hear from some other developers with perhaps more experience and hear what your thoughts on the matter are.

Thanks!

Comment: You were right, he was wrong. End of story.

Comment: If there are conflicts Apple can resolve them any way they want and that may change at any time. Your coworker seems to be lazy and not to be trusted to write code. Warnings are there for a purpose, not to be ignored.

Comment: @Zaph Yeah, I thought of adding that the fact that this is not a downright crash is just a courtesy on Apple's part... :)

Comment: However, let's not go overboard on the "warnings are a bad thing", because unfortunately lots of Apple's own classes (interface and otherwise) _do_ generate warnings, some of them quite serious, but there's nothing one can do about them.

Comment: Awesome thanks guys.  @Zaph I would give you props on your answer but I'm not seeing how to upvote you

Comment: @matt It would probably be more a courtesy if it would reliably crash rather than being undefined behavior.... :) Man can undefined behavior bite you.